# ASP.NET AuthenticationModule using token in url

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webforms, forms-authentication

I created a HttpModule and attached a AuthenticateRequest handler to check if token exists in querystring. There I remove token from querystring and redirect to the required page without token, starting a new request life cycle (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx) and building the Session normally using the cookie.

Example:

- User request: `example.com/example?token=12312kaasd12asd21ko323`
- AuthenticateRequest handler authenticates the user and redirects to `example.com/example`

Code:

```
public class TokenAuthenticationModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.AuthenticateRequest += this.CheckToken;
    }

    private void CheckToken(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;

        string token = context.Request.QueryString["token"];

        if (MyTokenClass.IsValid(token))
        {
            int userCode = DecryptToken(token);
            User user = GetUserFromDataBase(userCode);
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, false);
            context.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but `AuthenticateRequest` fires for all folders that my page uses, css, images etc.

I want to check if uri has a token parameter just once per page.

I can't use events after `AuthenticateRequest` because after that the `FormsAuthentication` will override the uri redirecting to login

```
example.com/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=example&token=12312kaasd12asd21ko323
```

I want to create a module between request and FormsAuthentication.

I can get redirectUrl after FormsAuthentication in the BasePage and redirects to the requested page, but this is a workaround that I'm trying to avoid.

Is it possible to create that module with this behaviour? How can I do it?

I'm using WebForms.

Thanks!